# SCORM 2004 3th edition, primary objective

Tags: scorm2004

I am working on a course that uses SCORM 2004 3th edition, and i have this problem. For very small amount of the people that are using the course (around 1%-1.5%) the course dose not register completion in the LMS after they are finish it. I am checking the difference between a all working cases and this 1% that did not managed to complete the course, and the only difference that I see is the primary objective. In the working ones the primary objective have "Success Status" as "passed" and on the 1% it dose not even exist.

I tried to read in several places what is the primary objective and all i understood is that it is something that is defined in the imsmanifest.xml (in my case it is not), and if it is not there the LMS will create at least one for the course. If you set the 'cmi.success_status' to passed and the 'cmi.completion_status' to "completed" the LMS will set the primary objective to 'passed' as well.

So, my question is, did I understood this correctly, or it works in totally different way. What is exactly the primary objective and is it my responsibility to somehow set this or it is the LMS that is responsible for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After X amount of months it turns out that the LMS that the client is using (SABA) is buggy and it dose have problems with SCORM 2004 (they have exactly the same problem with other courses, that are not related to mine). So what fixed my problem was, converting the course to SCORM 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

> Run-time data related to objectives (cmi.objectives.n.xxx) should not be initialized for an activity’s associated SCO unless an objective ID attribute is defined in the sequencing information (imsss:primaryObjective or imsss:objective).

For example if on cloud.scorm.com I do not specify a primary objective I do not get any cmi.objectives._count.  If I explicitly set a primary objective then it/they can show up

So you can define a primary objective in the imsmanifest.xml, but its possible the platform as you stated is defaulting one.  I've seen this occur on a platform before and it really goofs up the logic calculating the SCO's objective scaled scores when you have a rogue objective commonly with no data.  Not to say what you're encountering with the "satisfiedByMeasure".

My interpretation of what happened here was a misunderstanding/interpretation with the way the dev's implemented the Runtime Environment. There are "Global Objectives" and "Primary Objectives" but I (personal opinion) do not believe they should be adding a cmi.objective.0 unless one is physically present in your manifest, or added by 'other means' through the LMS Administration.  My .02 cents is this area of the specification caused confusion which lead to some of these behaviors.  Even how the LMS determines and stores these was not (again my opinion) laid out well in the specification and left room for interpretation.

The whole purpose of the Simple Sequencing and or Sequence and Navigation was to allow you (instructional designer, content developer or otherwise) the capability to bake-in a level of flow controls that (simple or complex) allow the LMS to manage the user navigation either through input (clicking on content / assets) or based on performance using rulesets.

There was a "[Impact Summary](https://adlnet.gov/assets/uploads/SCORM2004-3rd_ImpactSummary.pdf)" document written up to.